# What is this transformation called sqrt(max(x+1) - x)?

Tags: data-science, normal-distribution

so I had a response variable that was not normally distributed and was negatively skewed. So I tried many different approaches like using log, cube root but none did the trick. Finally I tried using sqrt(max(x+1) - x) and the distribution finally appeared to be normal. My problem is, I have read from some articles that the square root transformation is used for positively skewed data. Hence, my question is whether sqrt(max(x+1) - x) can be considered as a square root transform ? If not, what is it called then?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can still consider it a square root transformation, but it is one that is specifically designed to work with negative skews. The normal square root transformation works only well with positive skews.